# How do I get a non-standard non-repo version of python under package management?

Tags: package-management, python, ppa

For any number of reasons, I need a python version that isn't in mainline repositories.  Where should I look?

In my particular case I want 3.4 alpha/beta, but where should I look for non-standard python versions in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.4 is already packaged in the development series for Ubuntu 14.04. You can install the development version of Ubuntu if you really need to use the 3.4 beta, or you can attempt to backport the packages to a released version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Accepted, but I'm leaving my answer since it could fit with a wider use case of non-repo old/new versions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this in chat some time ago, and got a probably simple enough to compile 3.4 yourself... which is true.

I, however, thought it should be documented on-site that a good ppa to use for this purpose is the [deadsnakes repo](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes).  Reasoning is that if pip uses travis-ci... and travis-ci uses deadsnakes... I should get on the train or get out of the way.

I'm confident 3.4 will be there ahead of mainline adoption, if I need a testing environment.  So, it's not there yet, but it will be -- is probably the best answer I could have gotten.

Comment: You could also use the development version of Ubuntu, which already has 3.4 available in the repository.

Comment: @Dobey Nice... and I will in a VM now that I know it's there.  I just thought it bore noting on the SE scratchpad.